# No route matches [POST] "/tracking_configs/6" after submitting another remote form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I am working at the view for an edit action which contains one primary form for the model `TrackingConfig`, which submits normally (not remote), and another secondary remote form for fetching some data.

```
= form_for @tracking_config do |f|

  .event-fields
    = f.fields_for :tracking_event_configs do |ff|
      = render 'tracking_event_config_block', form: ff

  = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-danger'


= form_tag get_event_fields_tracking_configs_path, remote: true, method: :get do
  = select_tag :event_name, options_from_collection_for_select(TrackableEvent.all, :event_name, :event_name), prompt: 'Choose event to add'
  = submit_tag 'Add event config'
```

By loading the edit page directly and clicking on the submit button it sends a PATCH request to the update action, which works perfectly:

> Started PATCH "/tracking_configs/6"

But when I use the second form to add an item to the first form by rendering the HTML in a .js.erb view:

```
<%
  tracking_event_config_block = render(
    "tracking_event_config_block",
    form: ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.new(
      "tracking_config[tracking_event_configs_attributes][]",
      @tracking_event_config,
      self,
      {}
    )
  )
%>
$('.event-fields').append(
  '<%= j tracking_event_config_block %>'
)
```

Then pressing the Save button triggers a routing error:

> No route matches [POST] "/tracking_configs/6"

The strange thing is that the `_method` param is being sent in the correct way to the request:
[image]

The routes that I'm using are standard Rails resourceful routes:

```
  resources :tracking_configs, only: [:new, :index, :create, :edit, :update] do
    collection do
      get 'get_event_fields'
    end
  end
```

To mention that I use exactly the same forms for the #new action and it works well there.

EDIT: **UPDATE**: I am trying to simulate the request in Postman by sending the raw data. Even if the `_method` is specified to `patch` the request results in getting interpreted by Rails as a POST request:

```
Started POST "/data_collecting/tracking_configs/6" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-18 10:35:23 +0100 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/data_collecting/tracking_configs/6"):
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Form generated is still sent via POST, although it has an extra attribute called _methode.

See : [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)

I suggest that you use:

```
match 'a_route' => 'controller#method', via: [:patch, :post]
```

Comment: I edited my question to include the routes, which are standard Rails. It should work out of the box, yet there is this strange behavior when I use the 2nd form. The `_method` attribute you are talking about is sent in the request (see the screenshot attached to question)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the specific issue by changing this line in the js response that generates the html for the additional fields:

```
"tracking_config[tracking_event_configs_attributes][]",
```

to

```
"tracking_config[tracking_event_configs_attributes][#{@event_config_index}]",
```

where `@event_config_index` is a parameter I pass in the request.

It seems like Rails is completely confused by parameter names like `tracking_config[tracking_event_configs_attributes][]` in forms but I am pretty sure this is how I used it before and it has worked.